# Downloading MODIS data of cloud cover less than 10%

Tags: r, modis, cloud-cover

I use `ModisDownload` from `rts package` for downloading MODIS data. But is it possible to specify cloud cover and view angle before downloading? e.g. if I want to download MODIS data for cloud cover less than 10% and view angle of 10 degrees.

Comment: Which product are you talking about?

Comment: @TonyC It is MOD11A1 product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. The way you asked the question makes me think you are comparing MODIS products with Landsat, which allows you to specify cloud coverage as a threshold during data query. This is not the case with MODIS. However, you can deal with it yourself simply by using the associated cloud mask. In your specific case, the MOD11A1 product does provide daytime and nighttime clear-sky coverage, which can help you achieve that.

Also, the MOD11A1 product includes two bands recording the zenith angle of the observation at each pixel, which I believe can provide you with the information regarding the view angle.

Comment: Thanks @TonyC ! Actually I need time series of MOD11A1, but when I download it and crop, in some of the images there is not data or values are too high or low. So I wanted to download images with specified cloud cover and view angle. Though this information is provided as separate bands but that can only be used after download. And I have around 100 images so I was looking for a solution where I could specify these parameters before download.

Comment: @Richa No problem. Yes at first it may be a bit challenging to deal with this many files all at once. But the good thing about MODIS is that the data of the same product are highly consistent. So once you figure out a way to get what you want using a small sample of images, you can easily apply that method to all images.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if done via [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer). Once you locate an area of your interest you will have an option to filter the images based on **cloudiness** level on the top right and download them with ease via download button on the right. An example of such imagery can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGpAn.jpg) or you can view It on the platform directly [here](https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=45.43508&lng=8.43201&z=8&preset=passiveLowSensors&side=R&slider-id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-MS5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDAw-MzM5-NTM%3D&slider-b=NIR,Red&slider-expression=(B02-B01)%2F(B02%2BB01)&slider-anti&id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-MS5o-MTh2-MDQu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkx-MDAw-MzM5-NTM%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&cb=true&anti).